# Hibernate or Netbeans not allowing foreign key tables for reverse engineering

Tags: mysql, hibernate, netbeans-6.9

I am working on a small application with hibernate and JSF in netBeans IDE. My project works good with masters. Now I need to add one more table which contains relation with those master. The scenario is as follow

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `TABLE_1` (
`ID1` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`ID1_DESC` varchar(45) default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`ID1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$

delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `TABLE_2` (
`ID2` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`ID2_DESC` varchar(45) default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`ID2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$

delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `TABLE_3` (
`ID3` int(3) NOT NULL default '0',
`ID1` int(3) NOT NULL,
`ID2` int(3) NOT NULL,
`ID3_DESC` varchar(45) default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`ID3`),
KEY `FK_ID1_idx` (`ID1`),
KEY `FK_ID2_idx` (`ID2`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_ID1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID1`) REFERENCES `table_1` (`ID1`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_ID2` FOREIGN KEY (`ID2`) REFERENCES `table_2` (`ID2`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

Then I have tried generate reverse engineering file through reverse engineering wizard of netbeans it excepts only TABLE1 and TABLE2. It shows Table3 as Table3 (no primary key). Also it does not include Table3 in reverse engineering file.

My generated hibernate.cfg.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TESTSCHEMA?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When I remove foreign key it allows me to generate TABLE3 mapping file and POJO.
I am not able to understand why it is not allowing foreign key concept. 
Is it mysql table creation mistake or netbeans bug or hibernate problem????

Can any one provide me solution for this problem? thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. I am using mysql on windows so the default value of lower_case_table_names=2. I have set it to 1. Also rename all table to lower case.
Then tried to generate mapping and pojos....succeeded.

Conclusion

If you’re using Hibernate and a MySQL database running on windows, make sure that your table names are all in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

It generates the many-to-many relation ship in both table1 and table2 entities.If remove the foreign key relation then its created as one-to-many.Please shown the table1 and table2 entities.

Comment: Sorry but no need to do it.